How can I convert an HTML game into a Flutter Android app?
I have developed a game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and I would like to convert it into a Flutter Android app. I've heard that using WebView might be a possible solution, but I'm not sure how to properly implement this or if there are better alternatives.
Here are the details:
The game is fully functional as a web application.

It includes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files.

I want to run the game inside a Flutter And
roid app.


What would be the best approach to achieve this? Should I embed the game using WebView or is it better to rewrite the game in Flutter? Any guidance on how to set this up would be appreciated.
I have developed a game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and I would like to convert it into a Flutter Android app. I've heard that using WebView might be a possible solution, but I'm not sure how to properly implement this or if there are better alternatives.
What would be the best approach to achieve this? Should I embed the game using WebView or is it better to rewrite the game in Flutter? Any guidance on how to set this up would be appreciated.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.0
  flame: ^1.0.0
  
  flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/your_game.html
    - assets/js/
    - assets/css/

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('HTML Game in Flutter'),
        ),
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'assets/your_game.html',  // Point to your local HTML game
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(GameWidget(game: MyGame()));

class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);
    // Render your game elements
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    // Update your game logic
  }
}

